# Avoid recursive paths

Tags: 7, uri

On my site I've views and custom hook_menu.

Also if I don't use page arguments (or contextual filters on views), the system returns pages also when I try to add element on path.
Example:

- hook_menu define a "my-great-page" and if I try to go to "my-great-page/test", Drupal returns me the content on my-great-page

This occurs also with views and with many other paths.

Is there way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: i believe this is default bahaviour. This could help even though it applies to Views 2 [NON-EXISTENT URLS IN VIEWS 2](https://skvare.com/blog/non-existent-urls-views-2). The discussion in the comments deal with other paths as well.

Comment: I notice this becuase editors have insert broken href and our search engine was looping..